# Why when I try to display more than 30 elements in a RSS feed it will break the format?

Tags: php, xml, macos, google-chrome

Firstly, I am working on a mac and google chrome.

I am trying to create a RSS feed about the data hold in my database but when I try to show more than 30 item it breaks the format into a string.

```php
 <?php
    $rssfeed = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>';
    $rssfeed .= '<rss version="2.0">';
    $rssfeed .= '<channel>';
    $rssfeed .= '<title>My RSS feed</title>';
    $rssfeed .= '<link>http://www.mywebsite.com</link>';
    $rssfeed .= '<description>This is an example RSS feed</description>';
    $rssfeed .= '<language>en-us</language>';
    $rssfeed .= '<copyright>Copyright (C) 2009 mywebsite.com</copyright>';
 


 

      for($i = 0; $i < 35; $i++){
        $rssfeed .= '<item>';
        $rssfeed .= '<title>asd</title>';
        $rssfeed .= '<description>eneko</description>';
        $rssfeed .= '<link>https://www.uwe.ac.uk</link>';
        $rssfeed .= '<pubDate>' . date("D, d M Y H:i:s O", strtotime($date)) . '</pubDate>';
        $rssfeed .= '</item>';
      }
    $rssfeed .= '</channel>';
    $rssfeed .= '</rss>';
 
    echo $rssfeed;

header('Content-type: text/xml');

?>
```

When I try to print 15 times for example the result is this:

[Well formated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ypzA.png)

On the other hand, when I try to print 35 entries for example I got this result:

[Wrongly formatted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4dHa.png)

I have tried to do it too with the XMLwrite library but it will do the same thing.

Comment: View the source, not what you see in the browser

Comment: Then how can I make a form display another page with the view source included so the view source is automatically displayed when I submit the form

Comment: An XML document is not text. Do not attempt to treat it like text or you will fail. Use proper tools to create XML documents.

Comment: And don't ignore warnings and notices, they give you valuable information. Like the "cannot modify header" warning that your code is creating.